# search elements in a list are present in the dataframe column

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and struggling with this use case
I have a list of names and I need to search if any of these names are present I a particular column of a DataFrame.

my DataFrame has two column as shown below:

```
no.  |description
12342|my name is jack 
2345 |daniel is my neighbour
2122 |his wife sofia is my schoolmate
```

I have a list of names say list of names `{"jack","daniel"}`
now i need to traverse the description column of the DataFrame and see if any of the words from the list is present in the description column or not.

I tried using this piece of code  :

```
df_cleansing.filter("description".isin(listOfLines:_*))
```

but it showing compilation error. Any leads would be of great help.

Comment: What compilation error does it show?

Comment: you will have to write a udf function for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a `udf` function as below should work for you

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
// udf function for checking if any of the words in the 
// list is contained in the value of description column
def containsUdf = udf((strCol: String) => listOfLines.exists(strCol.contains))

//calling the udf function
df_cleansing.filter(containsUdf(col("description")))
```

which should give you

```
+-----+----------------------+
|no.  |description           |
+-----+----------------------+
|12342|my name is jack       |
|2345 |daniel is my neighbour|
+-----+----------------------+
```

Comment: how would i achieve if i  want to split the sentence into a string array and search in the list of names ..

Comment: `.map(sthToBoolean).contains(true)` is the same as `.exists(sthToBoolean)`, just slower.

Comment: I think you can also skip the `(_)` part, `listOfLines.exists(strCol.contains)` should also work.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan ..how can i make it return a boolean value..1 if found else 0

Comment: you can define udf function as `def containsUdf = udf((strCol: String) => if(listOfLines.exists(strCol.contains)) 1 else 0)` and then call the udf as `df_cleansing.withColumn("description", containsUdf(col("description")))`. I hope it helps.

Comment: as per my understanding .. the UDF would return 1 for each row if the keyword from list is contained else return 0.. then when i use                                           df_cleansing.withColumn("description", containsUdf(col("description"))) then i am comparing it to 1 or 0..please correct me if my understanding is not correct

Comment: not yet below is the code:def containsUdf = udf((strCol: String) => if(listOfLines.exists(strCol.contains)) 1 else 0) val addDummyColumn :(String)=>String=(data:String)=>{data}    UDF to add  coloumn
 val dummyColUDF= udf(addDummyColumn) 
   I am gettin an error here : if(df_cleansing.withColumn("description", containsUdf(col("description")))==1){
    val final_df = op.withColumn("output",dummyColUDF(lit("found")))
 }else
 {
    val final_df = op.withColumn("output",dummyColUDF(lit("not found"))) .. i am getting error in the if statement .. if found i have to update a coloumn found/not

Comment: why aren't you doing as I told you to do? just define the udf function and call it as i explianed in my comment above. did you do that? isn't that what you want

Comment: i will redefine my use case ..may be i have messed it up.. i have a list and dataframe as mentioned above originally in the question:if there is an element from the list present in the dataframe " description " coloumn then add a new coloumn to the dataframe and put "found" else put "not found". i am able to do individually each part like "searching from the list " as suggested by you and then creating a coloumn and putting value into it..but with that condition if(found from list(in th emanner given by you )) then put found else put "not found" in the new coloumn..is failing

Comment: you can always ask another question :)

Comment: i will ask a fresh question ..help me out there

Comment: sure I will as much as I can